# Peak Detector - Detecting Small Peaks

Tags: python, numpy

I am going through [Marcos Duarte's peak detector](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/demotu/BMC/blob/master/notebooks/DetectPeaks.ipynb) and understand every line, except for the part when he detects small peaks closer than the minimum peak distance:

```
if ind.size and mpd > 1:
        ind = ind[np.argsort(x[ind])][::-1]  # sort ind by peak height
        idel = np.zeros(ind.size, dtype=bool)
        for i in range(ind.size):
            if not idel[i]:
                # keep peaks with the same height if kpsh is True
                idel = idel | (ind >= ind[i] - mpd) & (ind <= ind[i] + mpd) \
                    & (x[ind[i]] > x[ind] if kpsh else True)
                idel[i] = 0  # Keep current peak
        # remove the small peaks and sort back the indices by their occurrence
        ind = np.sort(ind[~idel])
```

In particular, I do not understand this line:

```
idel = idel | (ind >= ind[i] - mpd) & (ind <= ind[i] + mpd) \
                        & (x[ind[i]] > x[ind] if kpsh else True)
```

I understand that he sorts the peak array (`ind`) by peak height and creates a bool array of the same size, initializing it with false values. Then he iterates through the `idel` array, checking first if the current value is 0 (false).

I have run the different Boolean comparisons of the next line individually but cannot figure out how he is using the `mpd`, as he is working with `ind` both at the array and element level. Can anybody give me a quick explanation? I am stuck at this point.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that `kpsh` is an option that overrides `mpd`. Normally if `mpd` is chosen, you can only see one peak in any given segment of length `2*mpd`. However, if `kpsh` chosen, an exception is made for peaks that share the same height, as it is a *tie situation*.

Now, let's analyze it:

`(ind >= ind[i] - mpd) & (ind <= ind[i] + mpd)` part checks FOR EACH element of `ind` if whether it is in the `mpd` vicinity of `ind[i]`, so it will return a boolean array of the same size as `ind`. I will call this `arr_mpd`. Assume for a second that there is no `kpsh`. What will happen is `idel | arr_mpd` will return `True` for indices `i` where `ind[i]` has already a peak defined in it's vicinity. Therefore it discards `ind[i]` by setting `idel[i]` to `TRUE` becasue later, `ind = np.sort(ind[~idel])` will take care of deleting them.

Now let's focus on `(x[ind[i]] > x[ind] if kpsh else True)`. I'm going to call this `arr_kpsh`.

- Case 1: `kpsh==False` makes `arr_kpsh` an array of `True`s. Since a bitwise_or operation is being done using `&`, `arr_mpd & arr_kpsh` will be equal to `arr_mpd` right away so `arr_kpsh` is made ineffective when `kpsh==False`.
- Case 2: `kpsh==True` is where the magic happens. `x[ind[i]] > x[ind]` checks element-wise whether the value of the peak corresponding to `ind[i]` is greater than any other peak indices has found up to that point. If that's the case, then it means it's not the same height (no need the check direct equality since a peak value can only be larger). If it's not greater however, that means there is another peak with the same height. This overrides that element on `arr_mpd & arr_kpsh` to `False`. If that element is also false in `idel` alraedy, then it will be kept, thus keeping same heights when `kpsh=True`.

I hope this helps

Comment: Yes, that is very helpful and solved my doubt. Thank you so much!